# How to use reverse scaling function with error bars?

Tags: plotting, warning-messages, scaling

I have data which I would like to plot along with the corresponding error bars:

```
{{{54927.7, -1.91044}, 
ErrorBar[38.2664, 0.0538982]}, {{55320.9, -1.97673}, 
ErrorBar[45.3592, 0.101486]}, {{55671.4, -2.15716}, 
ErrorBar[41.2234, 0.0258249]}, {{56032.9, -2.15957}, 
ErrorBar[38.8805, 0.0191277]}, {{56410.6, -2.14289}, 
ErrorBar[41.5501, 0.0189911]}, {{56787.2, -2.19703}, 
ErrorBar[38.1972, 0.00632055]}, {{57137.5, -2.1839}, 
ErrorBar[35.6098, 0.0084108]}, {{57493.3, -2.19994}, 
ErrorBar[38.0298, 0.00651633]}, {{57859.5, -2.19687}, 
ErrorBar[40.9682, 0.00658857]}}
```

I can use the `ErrorListPlot` function in mathematica just fine, however if I would like to reverse the y axis scale with the function `ScalingFunctions->"Reverse"` the error bars do not get plotted along with the data.....any suggestions on how to fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can post-process the `ErrorListPlot` output to reverse the vertical axis using `ReflectionTransform` and modify the ticks:

```
elp = ErrorListPlot[data];
Show[MapAt[GeometricTransformation[#, ReflectionTransform[{0, -1}]] &, elp, {1}], 
 PlotRange -> {1.8, 2.3}, AxesOrigin -> {Automatic, 2.3}, 
 Ticks -> {Automatic, Charting`FindTicks[{0, 1}, {0, -1}] }]
```

[image]

Alternatively,

```
Show[elp /. p : _Point| _Line :> GeometricTransformation[p, ReflectionTransform[{0, -1}]],
 PlotRange -> {1.8, 2.3}, AxesOrigin -> {Automatic, 2.3}, 
 Ticks -> {Automatic, Charting`FindTicks[{0, 1}, {0, -1}] } ]
```

> same picture

Comment: This works! Would you be able to explain to me though why the "MapAt" function is needed here and we cannot just use the "GeometricTransformation" function with inputting the ErrorListPlot instead of the "#" ?

Comment: @msuffak, You can also do `GeometricTransformation[elp[[1]], ReflectionTransform[{0, -1}]]` to get the graphics primitives. Then you need to wrap it with `Graphics` and add the options: ``Graphics[GeometricTransformation[elp[[1]], 
  ReflectionTransform[{0, -1}]], AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, 
 Axes -> True, PlotRange -> All, AxesOrigin -> {Automatic, 2.3}, 
 Ticks -> {Automatic, Charting`FindTicks[{0, 1}, {0, -1}]}]``. I find `MapAt` and `ReplaceAll` just convenient in that the options of `elp` are retained.